# AngularJS ng-repeat array index iteration

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, angularjs, cordova

I'm building a Cordova app for Android, and I have an array of entries that I am displaying in a list of cards using Ionic.

This is how I display them:

```
    <!-- // List of Cards // -->
    <div class="list card" ng-repeat="entry in entryDB">

      <!-- // Card Title // -->
      <div class="item item-divider">{{entry[1].link}}</div>
      <!-- // Card Contents // -->
      <div class="item item-body" ng-click="browse(entry[1].link)">
        <h2><b>{{entry[1].title}}</b></h2>
        <p>{{entry[1].contentSnippet}}</p>
        <p><a class="subdued">{{entry[1].publishedDate}}</a></p>
      </div>

    </div>
```

How can I update the index value for entry[index] for each object in the array, so that a new row is created in the list for each object in the array?

I have tried using a 'track by $index', but that did not work.

Also by the way I have tried using the standard way of showing the entires, but this is the only way it displays each entry separately by using a [index] to display each entry, if I remove this, it only creates one list item that contains the entire array.

I'm new to AngularJS and I've been tearing my hair out over this issue, I can imagine it's something super simple that I'm missing.

Comment: Not quite sure if I get your question right, but can't you just swap [1] with [$index]? edit: ah, nvm. Is entry itself an array?

Comment: I'm not really understanding what your question is....

Comment: Sorry for the vague question, I tried clarifying it now @erichardson30

Comment: You have to do entry[$index] instead of entry[1] along with 'track by $index'. Have you tried that already?

Comment: @JanS Yes, the entry it self is an array. So by just using the {{entry}}, it just displays the entire array.

Comment: @NMittal Yes - it still only displays one of the objects inside the array.

Comment: So you need to do a nested ng-repeat `<div ng-repeat="entry in entryDB"> <div class="list card" ng-repeat="item in entry">`

Comment: u could create variable in ng-repeat. init variable

Comment: @erichardson30 So in this case would that be doing: ng-repeat="item in entry" ?

Comment: Yep that's what I have there. That should work and get you what you need

Comment: @erichardson30 YESS! That worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem I will add as an answer to the question

Comment: When having a problem displaying data...show samples of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since entryDB is an array of arrays, in your ng-repeat entry is still an array that needs to be looped through and track by $index referencing $index will not get you what you're looking for inside of entry. If you want all of the items inside entry to display then you need a nested ng-repeat to access those items. Instead of :

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="entry in entryDB">
```

do :

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entryDB"> 
    <div class="list card" ng-repeat="item in entry">
        <!-- // Card Title // -->
        <div class="item item-divider">{{item.link}}</div>
        <!-- // Card Contents // -->
        <div class="item item-body" ng-click="browse(item.link)">
            <h2><b>{{item.title}}</b></h2>
            <p>{{item.contentSnippet}}</p>
           <p><a class="subdued">{{item.publishedDate}}</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```